# Difference between Beta process and Beta regression?

Tags: regression, distributions, generalized-linear-model, terminology, stochastic-processes

In a layman language, how the difference can be defined between statistical process and the same named GLM such as poisson processes and poisson regression or beta processes and beta regression? How are they related?

Comment: Have you consulted definitions?  What do they say?